# How can I use typeof operator this way?

Tags: typescript

is it possible to use operator typeof to get type of the newly created object instead of its type?

Here is an example:

```
type Options = {
    a?: boolean
    b?: boolean
    c?: boolean
}

const option: Options = {
    a: true,
    b: true
}

typeof option; // { a: true, b: true } or atleast { a: boolean, b: boolean }
               // not { a?: boolean, b?: boolean, c?: boolean }
```

Comment: Remove the explicit type annotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have explicit type annotation, TS will use it.
The best way is to use `satisfies` operator which checks that the constant satisfies given type shape, but preserves the detailed type of the constant.

```ts
type Options = {
    a?: boolean;
    b?: boolean;
    c?: boolean;
}

const option = {
    a: true,
    b: true
} satisfies Options;

type OptionType = typeof option; 
//   ^?
// type OptionType = {
//     a: true;
//     b: true;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgEMB%20ALigCMkkAbCYlAbgKKoutoadaKgDGnGvUYs8AXzx4BqNMChJ4yFFlxtCxSsABOAVwgAaDdW36IkqGmKI0AMwQQMcRHNZ5QkWMtQAVcNDYnhBIdoo%20LFB4APTRRAB6pEA)

Comment: Thanks, but the next question is: Is there a way to use satisfies or something different with similar functionality in function parameter?

Comment: There is new feature in TS5 called [const Type Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) which might be what you are looking for. Probably it is best to ask a follow-up question with precise description of your scenario.